# install_github no longer works (in R) after upgrading Mac

Tags: r

I've recently upgraded my Mac to Version 10.12.1 (Sierra). I also upgraded XQuartz and CUDA (just in case) to the latest available versions, and certainly R to Version 3.3.2 (the latest one too).

But then, install_github() no longer works. See the error message in the attached picture.

[image]

Comment: what is the `sessionInfo()` output and which version of `callr` do you have. Have you updated this packages as well?

Comment: So we are trying to install GitHub version of `devtools` using existing `devtools::install_github`?

Comment: @zx8754: Yes. Apparently, install_github doesn't work with any package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was already reported, and fixed so it seems, see the [following link](https://github.com/MangoTheCat/callr/issues/17).

The issue boils down to the fact that `callr` is used to install the packages. If you have not installed `callr` before, this sadly also includes `callr` itself. So now we are in the situation that we need `callr` to install `callr`, but we can't install `callr` because `callr` is not installed. You can fix this by installing `callr` seperately first (see the link I provided).

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. I use remotes (as suggested in the link) and it works now.